# How do I get logs from localstack when using APIGateway with Lambda Integration?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, localstack

I am running localstack to test out API Gateway with Lambda integration

In localstack docker logs I see

```
2023-03-04T11:40:41.408  INFO --- [uest_thread)] l.s.a.lambda_executors     : Running lambda: arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:000000000000:function:workflow-api-jobs-handler
2023-03-04T11:40:42.059  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_2] localstack.request.http    : GET /restapis/nb1kwykev1/dev/_user_request_/jobs => 500
```

But how do I know why the request leads to 500? How do I obtain the lambda logs perhaps?

---

If it helps, the lambda function in qn looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    fiberadapter "github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-go-api-proxy/fiber"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

var fiberLambda *fiberadapter.FiberLambda

func init() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.JSON(map[string]any{
            "hello": "world",
        })
    })

    app.Get("/jobs", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        name := c.Query("name")
        return c.JSON(map[string]any{
            "name": name,
        })
    })

    fiberLambda = fiberadapter.New(app)
}

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    return fiberLambda.ProxyWithContext(ctx, req)

}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

---

Update: Managed to test lambda like:

```
awslocal apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id $API_ID --resource-id $RESOURCE_ID --http-method GET --path-with-query-string '/jobs?name=xxx' --region ap-southeast-1 --debug --output json
```

Which works ... just that not sure why I cannot get the `name` query param

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "body": "{\"name\":\"\"}",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": "11"
    }
}
```

But if I try the same request thru browser, its

```
Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Cloudwatch Logs. The logs of a lambda executed through the Api Gateway can be retrieved by querying the [log groups and streams filled during the lambda execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html). In particular, each lambda has its own group, that is created in case it does not exist yet. The log group of a lambda matches the pattern `/aws/lambda/lambda_name`.

I have written a script to get all the logs from the lambda groups:

```
LOG_GROUPS_OUTPUT="$(awslocal logs describe-log-groups --query 'logGroups[?starts_with(logGroupName, `/aws/lambda`) == `true`].logGroupName')"
read -ra LOG_GROUP_NAMES <<< "$LOG_GROUPS_OUTPUT"

for LOG_GROUP_NAME in "${LOG_GROUP_NAMES[@]}"
do
    echo "********* Logging group $LOG_GROUP_NAME"
    LOG_STREAMS_OUTPUT="$(awslocal logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name "$LOG_GROUP_NAME" --query 'logStreams[*].logStreamName')"
    read -ra LOG_STREAM_NAMES <<< "$LOG_STREAMS_OUTPUT"

    for LOG_STREAM_NAME in "${LOG_STREAM_NAMES[@]}"
    do
        echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++ Logs for $LOG_GROUP_NAME -> $LOG_STREAM_NAME"
        awslocal logs get-log-events --log-stream-name "$LOG_STREAM_NAME" --log-group-name "$LOG_GROUP_NAME" --query 'events[*].message'
    done
# sed here is necessary because with text output the logs are (inexplicably) tab-separated
done | sed 's/\t/\n/g'
```

**Note**: I have changed the default output type of aws cli commands from `json` to `text`. If you do not want to do that, you just have to append the option `--output text` to the `awslocal ...` commands.

A couple of things about the script:

- I have used a filter expression to consider only the log groups created by lambdas. Filter expressions are well documented [here](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#filterexpressions). The expression

  ```
  starts_with(logGroupName, `/aws/lambda`) == `true`
  ```

  returns only the group names starting with `/aws/lambda`.
- For each log group name (`describe-log-groups`), I get all the log stream names (`describe-log-streams`) in that group and then all the log events (`get-log-events`) associated to each of the log stream. In this case, the `text` output format is very useful because we can re-create the same raw logs we would see if we inspected the logs of a lambda executed with a `awslocal lambda invoke`. For some reasons, the logs are concatenated using the TAB: this is why I have `sed`ed the output and replaced the TAB with a newline.